# Linux (Ubuntu) ioctl KDGETLED/KDGKBLED always 0

Tags: linux

Code snippet below; basically, I am grabbing the active vt and issuing an ioctl KDGETLED against that terminal for the current state of the capslock/numlock/scrolllock keys and I always get result=0, regardless of the state of the lock keys.

I've tried this on multiple Linux boxes, all running variants of Ubuntu (e.g. Mint).  I've tried other fds for the KDGETLED command such as "/dev/tty", "/dev/console", 0, etc.  I'm running into the same problem with KDGKBLED.  Are others experiencing the same issue, am I doing something silly, am I running into poorly written drivers, or something else?

```
int fd;
vt_stat stat;
fd = open("/dev/tty0", O_RDONLY);
if (ioctl(fd, VT_GETSTATE, &stat) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on VT_GETSTATE\n");
    exit(1);
}
close(fd);
char tty[128];
sprintf(tty, "/dev/tty%d", stat.v_active);
printf("Query tty: %s\n", tty);
char result;
fd = open(tty, O_RDWR | O_NDELAY, 0);
if (ioctl(fd, KDGETLED, &result) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on KDGETLED\n");
    exit(1);
}
close(fd);
printf("LED flag state: %d\n", result);
```

Thanks, in advance, to all who review my question.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the driver code, especially the `struct file_operations` instance for that driver, and check the function assigned to the `.ioctl` member - if that is poorly coded (I've seen a lot of shitty stuff happening in ioctls) then that is definitely your issue.

In this case I am pretty sure it is the drivers fault. As long the ioctl command shows no compile error, everything - especially error handling and input checking - is the task of the driver.